# Angular2 pipe not working for input

Tags: html, angular, typescript, pipe

I'm using angular2 inbuilt pipe percent in my HTML

```
<input class="ibox1 rightalign" type="text" [ngModel]="_note.StudentPercent| percent:'.5-5'" ngControl="StudentPercent" pattern="^[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$" #StudentPercent="ngForm">
```

its working & display correct data to input box, but when I change the value of a field pipe doesn't work.

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have reapply filter on your model value on change of `_note.StudentPercent` input. You could use `ngModelChange` handler for the same.

```
<input class="ibox1 rightalign" type="text" 
   [ngModel]="_note.StudentPercent| percent:'.5-5'" 
   (ngModelChange)="changeToPercent(_note.StudentPercent,'.5-5')" 
   ngControl="StudentPercent" pattern="^[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$"
   #StudentPercent="ngForm" />
```

**Code**

```
changeToPercent(percent, format){
   //make sure PercentPipe in declarations & providers of NgModule
   this._note.StudentPercent = new PercentPipe().transform(percent, format)
}
```

Comment: getting exception:  Cannot have a pipe in an action expression.

Comment: @srashtisj I guess you can't use `Pipes` directly on event action, basically you need call method of component & do this thing inside component and assign back to model like `(ngModelChange)="_note.StudentPercent = doApplyPipe(_note.StudentPercent)" ` & where `doApplyPipe` will return result

Comment: yeah! but if I use this approach, I have to convert the value when is save it. like 0.24 => 24.00000% then while saving 24.00000% => 0.24000 ... is there is any other approach to use pipe?

Comment: @srashtisj see generally Pipe has been used to display something else based on model value, you don't really change actually model value, Apparently you tweak it.